# Bundle items(simple products) with Custom Variants and Options in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to add simple products with custom variants as items to my Bundle Product.
But Magento doesn't allow it.

> http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product

Is there any way, by tweaking the code, such that I can add simple products with custom options as Bundle items ?